# How to return different outputs with each call to a mock method

Tags: matlab, unit-testing, mocking

I am cross posting this [question I asked](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/357200-how-can-i-make-a-mock-method-return-different-answers) on MATLAB Answers.

---

I am trying to use the new MATLAB mocking framework to test a class method that computes a running variance of a stream of image frames. The input to the method would normally come from another data class. What I would like to do is to have a mock that returns a normally distributed random frame each time it gets called, and then have a test that checks to see if, after some large number of frames, the returned variance is 1 (within a tolerance).

If I write my method like this:

```
    function mock = makeMock(obj)
        [mock, b] = createMock(obj, 'AddedMethods', {'r'});
        import matlab.mock.actions.AssignOutputs;
        rng(1)
        x = @() randn(obj.rows, obj.cols);
        when(withAnyInputs(b.r), repeat(32, AssignOutputs(x())));
    end
```

Then when the output is assigned, `randn` is evaluated and the output is static, so all my frames are the same. The second thing I tried was to add multiple frames all at once as a list:

```
    function mock = makeMock(obj)
        [mock, b] = createMock(obj, 'AddedMethods', {'r'});
        import matlab.mock.actions.AssignOutputs;
        rng(1)
        x = num2cell(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols, 32), [1 2]);
        when(withAnyInputs(b.r), AssignOutputs(x{:}));
    end
```

This still gives only the first frame because `AssignOutputs` `deal`s its values to the output variables, and so I'm always only requesting the first one.

The last ugly thing I tried was:

```
        when(withAnyInputs(b.r), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)), ...
            AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols))) ...
            )))))))))))))))))))))))))))))));
```

This gives me an error that says that I am nested too deep.

I will note that the methods I'm trying to test want the whole mock object as an input, not just the frame, so just passing in a random frame isn't possible. It's part of a much, much larger code base and so simply rewriting the method under test to take the frame directly is not currently possible without significantly refactoring many others as well, so I'm stuck doing the test this way for now.

Is there an elegant way to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted an answer over on MATLAB Answers:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/357200-how-can-i-make-a-mock-method-return-different-answers#answer_282110

To summarize:

- There's no clean way to do this
- However, one can build up the list of actions in a loop

---

```
import matlab.mock.actions.AssignOutputs;
[mock, b] = createMock(obj, 'AddedMethods', {'r'});
rng(1)
n = 32;
action = AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols));
for i = 1:n-1
    action = action.then(AssignOutputs(randn(obj.rows, obj.cols)));
end
when(withAnyInputs(b.r), action);
```